# Orbeon Forms: How to populate a control value via an Action

Tags: orbeon

Forgive the simple question, but how can I pass a value into a control via an Action.

What I'm trying to achieve is to display a message popup with two buttons, and depending on the button pressed, I then want to populate a control value:

```
            <xf:action observer="Message1-control" event="DOMActivate">

                <xf:label>Alert Button</xf:label>

                <xf:message>You pressed the Message 1 button</xf:message>

                <!-- Here is where we want to write the value back to a control  -->

            </xf:action>
```

I've tried all sorts of synyax, but I'm struggling to get it right

Comment: Try to get some inspiration here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407379/how-to-send-an-email-using-an-orbeon-form-button-click . I thing using own `xxf:dialog` will be good idea https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/controls/dialog#declaring-a-dialog-control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make demo form for you https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/2e978a87be5ce4112d9b008dd481ae935040861c

I use `xxf:show` and `xxf:dialog` to show modal popup with two controls. In button in modal I use `xf:setvalue` to propagate value from input and `xxf:hide` to hide window.

```
<xh:html xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
         xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>Untitled Form</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true" xxf:analysis.calculate="true">

            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>
                    <section-1>
                        <grid-1>
                            <AgeOutput/>
                            <BtnShowDialog/>
                             <btnDialogBox/>
                             <textBoxDialog/>
                        </grid-1>
                        
                    </section-1>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Bindings -->
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                    <xf:bind id="grid-1-bind" ref="grid-1" name="grid-1">
                        <xf:bind id="AgeOutput-bind" name="AgeOutput" ref="AgeOutput" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                        <xf:bind id="BtnShowDialog-bind" ref="BtnShowDialog" name="BtnShowDialog"/>
                         <xf:bind id="textBoxDialog-bind" name="textBoxDialog" ref="textBoxDialog"
                                 xxf:whitespace="trim"/>
                              <xf:bind id="btnDialogBox-bind" ref="btnDialogBox" name="btnDialogBox"/>
                        
                    </xf:bind>
                    
                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>

            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:readonly="true" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>test</application-name>
                    <form-name>age_dialog</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en">Untitled Form</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                    <created-with-version>2021.1.6.202211071741 PE</created-with-version>
                    <library-versions>
                        <orbeon>14</orbeon>
                        <app>2</app>
                    </library-versions>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Attachments -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments/>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- All form resources -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                        <section-1>
                            <label>Untitled Section</label>
                        </section-1>
                        <AgeOutput>
                            <label/>
                            <hint/>
                            
                        </AgeOutput>
                        <BtnShowDialog>
                            <label>Show dialog</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </BtnShowDialog>
                        <textBoxDialog>
                            <label>Age</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </textBoxDialog>
                        <btnDialogBox>
                            <label>Send</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </btnDialogBox>
                        
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>

            
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
                <fr:section id="section-1-section" bind="section-1-bind">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                    <fr:grid id="grid-1-grid" bind="grid-1-bind">
                        <fr:c y="1" x="1" w="6">
                                <xf:input id="AgeOutput-control" bind="AgeOutput-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/AgeOutput/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/AgeOutput/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                    
                                </xf:input>
                            </fr:c>
                        <fr:c y="1" x="7" w="6">
                            <xf:trigger id="BtnShowDialog-control" bind="BtnShowDialog-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/BtnShowDialog/label"/>
                    
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/BtnShowDialog/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    
                                <xxf:show event="DOMActivate" dialog="my-dialog-id"/> 
                                
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </fr:c>
                    </fr:grid>
                </fr:section>
                
                 <xxf:dialog id="my-dialog-id" appearance="full" level="modal" close="true" draggable="true"
                            visible="false">
                    <xf:label>Age confirm</xf:label>
                   
                     <xf:input id="textBoxDialog-control" bind="textBoxDialog-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/textBoxDialog/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/textBoxDialog/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                    </xf:input>
                     
                    <xf:trigger id="btnDialogBox-control" bind="btnDialogBox-bind">
                        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/btnDialogBox/label"/>
                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/btnDialogBox/hint"/>
                        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        <xf:action event="DOMActivate">
                                    <!-- Operation to perform -->
                            <xf:setvalue ref="//AgeOutput" value="//textBoxDialog"/>
                            
                        </xf:action>
                        <xxf:hide event="DOMActivate" dialog="my-dialog-id"/> 
                    </xf:trigger>
                     
                </xxf:dialog>
                
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```